# My function in jQuery shows a text in front of the output even though the function self already works

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function, sidebar, slug

I came up with an solution for not showing an sidebar in Wordpress when this is not filled with widgets. I did this by calling for the slug from the current page and named my sidebars the same as the slugs from my pages.

Thanks to some help I get this thing working but the problem is I see the name of the slug appears in front of the sidebar. For an image example [Click here](http://cl.ly/image/0I3U1K1A3j2t). For the live example [Click here](http://www.nickelanddime.nl/welovebeef/beef-abc/).

My current code is:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( the_slug() ) ) { ?>
    <ul id="sidebar">
       <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } else { ?>
    //empty
<?php } ?>
```

What goes wrong that causes this problem? Would be great to see the slug text disappear. Thanks already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `the_slug()` outputs the value of the slug (via `echo`), *as well* as returning it.

Simply pass `false` (`the_slug(false)`), so that the value is *only returned* and ***not*** `echo`'d.